# C: getopt with list of acceptable optarg. What is the best practice?

Tags: c, data-structures, hash

I am writing a C program which is a frontend to a myriad tools. This fronted will be launched like this:

```
my-frontend --action <AN ACTION>
```

As all the tools have the same prefix, let say for this example this prefix is "foo". I want to concatenate "AN ACTION" to this prefix and exec this (if the tool exists).

I have written something but my implementation uses strcmp to test that "AN ACTION" is a valid action. Even if this works, I do not like it. So I am looking for a nicer solution that would do the same. The list of possibilities is pretty small (less than 10) and static (the list is "hardcoded") but I am sure there is a more "C-ish" way to do this (using a struct or something like that). As I am not a C expert, I am asking for your help.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [getopt_long](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html#Getopt-Long-Options). Its part of the standard C library. For full documentation on how C programs are supposed to handle arguments in a standard UNIX way, [check this](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html).

The above should give you the argument. But I see your problem is more than that. Dealing with multiple back-ends can be done like this:

```
struct cmds {
        char *name;
        void (*cmd)(int argc, char **argv);
};
```

You could declare a cmd_table like this:

```
struct cmds cmd_table[] = {
        { "backend1", backend1_exec },
        { "backend2", backend2_exec },
        ...
};
```

`backend1_exec()` and `backend2_exec()` are just functions which really do the grunt work for executing the real backend for you.

Then in your `main()` function just loop over the entries comparing each entry in the `cmd_table` with the argument, and then calling the corresponding backend function like this:

```
if (strcmp(cmdname, cmd_table[i].name)) {
        *(cmd_table[i].cmd)(argc, argv);
}
```

Yeah, there's nothing wrong with using `strcmp()` if you just got 10 entries in the table. Its not a performance critical section of your program, so I wouldn't worry too much about that. This method is a popular way of handling this, from what I have seen (that does not make it authoritative, but might help reassure you, that you're not doing anything wrong).

Comment: You did not understand my initial question. I have written the whole program using getopt_long. I can get optarg and stuff like that. The thing is simply, that given a list of acceptable choices, I want to trash all optarg values not member of this list. Currently I doing if (!strcmp (arg, "valid optarg")) ... I do not like this and I am pretty sure I could "automate" this using a data-structure (like a map or a hashtable) and immediately trash non-valid optarg without comparing agains each list members. I hope I am clear. Thank you